# power BI reports server contents embedding into saas application

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

I have published Power BI Desktop reports to on premises version of Power BI, now I need to embed these reports to a SAAS application for my customers. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can embed these reports by adding `?rs:embed=true` to their URL and putting this into iFrame. See [Quickstart: Embed a Power BI Report Server report using an iFrame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/quickstart-embed#capturing-the-url-parameter).

Comment: That's great ,but one thing i need to clear we have customers that would not be on our domain could they access the reports outside the organization and what are the steps to do this ?

Comment: This functionality in still in the [roadmap only](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/19953286-embed-power-bi-report-server-reports-into-extranet).

Answer (score 0):

My approach on this would be  to use the Power BI .NET SDK with the Power BI JavaScript API to embed Power BI into an application .

Your starting point should be the tutorial from MSDN where you will learn how to:

1) Register an application in Azure.

2) Embed a Power BI report into an application using your Power BI tenant.

**Prerequisites**

To get started, you're required to have:

A Power BI Pro account.

A Microsoft Azure subscription.

You need to have your own Azure Active Directory tenant setup.

If you're not signed up for Power BI Pro, sign up for a free trial before you begin.

If you don’t have an Azure subscription, create a free account before you begin.

Source : [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers)